# How to support all devices( Both mobile and Tablets) in android?

Tags: android, device

My app is designed for all devices (both mobile and tablet). But Some devices are not supported in play store publish. I have included my manifest file also.

What I have did mistake ?

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:resizeable="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="240"
                  />
<compatible-screens>

    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />


    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

   <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: Maybe it's Minimum SDK that you support. did you check this?

Comment: post the min and max support versions also.

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"
         />

Comment: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />` set this and try.

Comment: But some device with higher sdk are not supported...why???

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code in manifest file

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is that you have `<compatible-screens>`. If you want to support all screen sizes and densities, delete your `<compatible-screens>` element. As it stands, you are missing some densities.

Also note that "all devices" runs counter to your `<supports-screens>` element, where you say that there is a minimum size of 240dp along one side. This, however, is not being used for Play Store filtering, at least according to the documentation, last I checked.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure if you use any features such as telephony etc that the uses-feature option is configured in the androidmanifest.xml

e.g.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

There's quite a few of these for things like bluetooth wifi etc so if any devices don't have these features but you still want the app to install on them then that "required" flag will need to be set.